# how to enable explorer view in sharepoint 2010 and moss 2007 for document libraries?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, document-library

I have already enabled webclient service but i think I m missing something tht has to be done...

Answer (score 2):

The client needs to run IE 32-bit and have a single recent Office 32-bit installed.
Mixed Office enviroments often seems to break the explorer view.

BTW should probably be asked on serveroverflow